# Is there a way to select an option from the right-click menu from a Windows Batch Script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, terminal

So I want to write a script to navigate to my music-folder, "right-click" on the 'New MP3' folder, and select "Add to VLC media player's Playlist".  Is there any way to get drop-down menu options like this in a script (bash, python, whatever)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet..?

Comment: In the terminal??? No way.

Comment: I think that you are looking for is a shell extension.

Comment: @ Rafael, Yeah, I didn't think so, but it would be really cool if it was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is a bit vague, and you're talking about Bash and Windows at the same time, but I'm assuming you're on a Windows machine and want to automatically add your "New MP3" folder to VLC's playlist.

To achieve this, open Notepad, and save the following line to a `.bat` file:

```
"C:\Path\To\vlc.exe" --one-instance --playlist-enqueue "C:\Path\To\New MP3"
```

This will add the files in the specified folder to VLC.

Comment: Sorry, I conflated Bash and Batch.

Comment: Would it be at all possible to explain why/how this works, or how you knew '--playlist-enqueue' would work as a command, as well as why the '--one-instance' is necessary? Its fine if not (I will try to look it up).  But I am more curious about where to find such info in general, not just for a specific example like this one.  Anyways, thanks; now I will actually try it out.

Comment: Sure. I saw your question, didn't know the answer but thought it was interesting. I [searched Google](https://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=mFEQU9_0KYGH8QervICoBw#q=windows+cmd+vlc+add+to+playlist) and found [this forum](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=65006) as the top hit. The OP there has written something about running `vlc.exe` from the command prompt with parameters `--started-from-file --playlist-enqueue "Song1.mp3"`.

Comment: I then did [another search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=vlc+command+line&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-nightly&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=oVIQU-_dNIOH8QfV8oDQDA#channel=fflb&q=vlc+command+line+add+file&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial) and found [this blog](http://resque.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/add-a-file-to-the-current-vlc-playlist-from-the-terminal-command-line/). Then I downloaded VLC player and started putting everything together and tested it.